Multiples are not smaller, for naturals.
Attached below is an image of a proof laid out in a math reasoning textbook I am reading:

In particular, I am hung up about the final paragraph. Namely, we show that $d$ is a multiple of $gcd(a, b)$ and conclude that $d \geq gcd(a, b)$. But how is that so? A multiple, by definition, can be less than the multiplier. The only way in which we may be certain that $d \geq gcd(a, b)$ is if the term $mk + nl \geq 1$.
If we take a step back, we can make some conclusions about m and n. That is, because $a = gcd(a, b)m$, $a \geq 1$, and $gcd(a,b) \geq 1$ (because a and b are natural numbers), $m \geq 1$. We can argue similarly to show that $n \geq 1$.
However, I have a harder time establishing inequalities about k and l that would allow us to conclude that $mk + nl \geq 1$
As long as I am not missing something trivial, why was this justification omitted from the proof? This seems like a necessary step so that one can make such a big jump.

Both $d$ and the gcd are positive integers, and for positive integers a multiple can't be less than the factor.

@lulu I see. For a given positive factor, there are certainly multiples that are less than the factor, but these multiples must be negative. For instance, suppose we have the factor 3. There are certainly multiples of 3 less than 3 (-3, -6, etc.), but all of these multiples are negative. So, knowing that the gcd(a, b) is positive and knowing that d is positive forces the conclusion that d must be greater than or equal to gcd(a, b).

To stress:  you also need that the terms be integers.  After all $\frac 12\times 3<3$.  But:   If $m>0$ then $dm<m\iff (d-1)m<0\iff d-1<0\iff d<1$.  But if $d$ is a positive integer, it can't be $<1$.

Please delete the question once all is clear, since it is a duplicate.

A numbers factors are always less than or equal to the number. A multiple of a number trivially has absolute value greater than or equal to the number. For example multiples of 2 have the form $$ m=2k $$$$ k \in \mathbb{Z} $$
gcd(a,b) is the largest number that divides a and b. Since if f is a divisor -f is also a divisor we can define gcd(a,b) to be positive and 1 is a common divisor for every number so it always exists.
We can now write $$a=gcd(a,b)m$$$$b=gcd(a,b)n$$
for m and n integers, the sign of and and b is the same as the sign of m and n.
You don't have to justify these quantities being bigger than zero. We assumed this when we constructed the set we are considering elements from. The underlying groundwork of the integers, sets and logic allow us to make these arguments like construcing a set, we showed it is not empty. Since d must take the from $$d=ak + bl$$ k, l are integers and d is positive we write d as $$d=gcd(a,b)mk+gcd(a,b)nl = gcd(a,b)(mk+nl)$$
d is by assumption positive so we know our expression on the left, equal to d, is positive. This shows d is a multiple of gcd(a,b). Again since if g divides e then -g divides e so we are considering gcd(a,b) to be positive and d is positive.
Where your confusion seems to lie is that a multiple of z has larger absolute value or equal to z. so we can say $$d \geq gcd(a,b) \geq 1 > 0$$
d has been shown to be a common divisor of a and b and by definition of gcd(a,b)
d must equal to gcd(a,b).
Showing a numbers multiples are greater than or equal the number could be an exercise. I see boiling down to the absolute value properties and ordering of the natural numbers.
